# Using Javascript in HTA file to read/write from Windows registry

Tags: javascript, windows, registry, hta, wsh

I'm currently attempting to write Javascript in order to read and write from the Windows registry in an HTA file. Here is the current code I am using to write:

```
writeInRegistry = function (sRegEntry, sRegValue) {
    Regpath = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\CompanyName\\CompanyValues\\" + sRegEntry;

    try {
        var oWSS = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");

        oWSS.RegWrite(Regpath, sRegValue, "REG_DWORD");
        oWSS = null;


    } catch (e) {
        alert('Error trying to write "' + sRegValue + '" to registry entry "' + sRegEntry + '"');
    }
}
```

Unfortunately when I check the values in regedit, they remain unchanged. I made sure to double check that the registry path is exactly the same as I have it in javascript. It doesn't return an error, so I'm assuming the path is correct.

I also attempted to try

```
var oWSS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
```

as referred to in this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x05fawxd) page, instead of

```
var oWSS = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
```

but that just gave me more problems.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I proposed an alternate approach without testing your code first. However, after testing, I have completely changed my original answer.

Comment: I ran your code and it worked perfectly. Make sure you run the registry editor (regedit) as well as your HTA application as an Administrator, to observe the changes that your code made.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a sample HTA HTML Application including functions writeinRegistry() and readFromRegistry() function based on your code. It wrote a value to the registry and retrieved it. The question is where did it place it. After searching the registry, I found it under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\VirtualStore\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432None\CompanyName\CompanyValues. This is because:

- I was running this on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine but executing the 32-bit version of MSHTA.exe (default)
- I was running as a regular user not elevated

So, then, I created a Windows shortcut to C:\Windows\System32\MSHTA.exe TheNameOfMyScript.hta. To ensure I was running the 64-bit version and then I executed the shortcut with elevation (Run the shortcut as Administrator). After doing this, the registry key under the HKLM branch updated.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>RegTest</title>
<script language="JavaScript">
function writeInRegistry(sRegEntry, sRegValue)
{
  var regpath = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\CompanyName\\CompanyValues\\" + sRegEntry;
  var oWSS = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
  oWSS.RegWrite(regpath, sRegValue, "REG_DWORD");
}

function readFromRegistry(sRegEntry)
{
  var regpath = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\CompanyName\\CompanyValues\\" + sRegEntry;
  var oWSS = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
  return oWSS.RegRead(regpath);
}

function tst()
{
  writeInRegistry("Version", "101");
  alert(readFromRegistry("Version"));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Click here to run test: <input type="button" value="Run" onclick="tst()"
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that when you update registry keys in code whilst `regedit.exe` is open/running it is a good idea to press `F5` in `regedit` to refresh it after the code ran.