# how to add registry value by hta or html file

Tags: html, vbscript, key, registry, hta

i need add a registry value by html file
my Registry value will be added in the Run
and

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\
```

please how to creat this file by language vbscript in html file
and I tested this

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Active Desktop Recovery</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
  APPLICATIONNAME="Active Desktop Recovery"
  ID="MyHTMLapplication"
  VERSION="1.0"/>
</head>

<script language="VBScript">
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Gmail\Gmil", "Value", "REG_SZ"
</script>

<body bgcolor="white">

<!--Add your controls here-->09:49 
<td><input name="txtComputerName" title="Enter a the computer you wish to query" TYPE="TEXT" SIZE="15"></td>
<td><input name="txtUserID" title="Enter available User ID" TYPE="TEXT" SIZE="50"></td>
<INPUT NAME="btnClearCSC" title="Clear CSC" TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Clear CSC">
<INPUT NAME="btnFindUser" title="Clear CSC" TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Find User">
<!--{{InsertControlsHere}}-Do not remove this line-->
</body>
</html>
```

thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Comment: i testing this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884347/using-javascript-in-hta-file-to-read-write-from-windows-registry but not right

Comment: `WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Gmail\Gmil", txtUserID.value, "REG_SZ"`

Comment: @NumEduc Did you mean you must run this HTA as Administrator ?

Comment: Hackoo i do not know

Comment: Then you need to give context. Your code will write a value called `Gmil` (maybe misspelt) under the `gmail` key with the value of `Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Active Desktop Recovery</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
  APPLICATIONNAME="Active Desktop Recovery"
  ID="MyHTMLapplication"
  VERSION="1.0"/>
</head>
<script language="VBScript">
Option Explicit
Dim WshShell,Title
Title = "Active Desktop Recovery" 
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'*************************************************************************
Sub Write2Registry()
    WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Gmail\Gmil",txtUserID.Value, "REG_SZ"
end sub
'*************************************************************************
Sub ReadFromRegistry()
On Error Resume Next
Dim MyKey
    MyKey = WshShell.RegRead("HKCU\Software\Gmail\Gmil")
    If Err <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Number & vbcr & Err.Description,vbCritical,Title
    Else
        MsgBox MyKey,vbInformation,Title
    End If  
End Sub
'*************************************************************************
Sub DeleteKeyFromRegistry()
On Error Resume Next
Dim MyKey
    MyKey = WshShell.RegDelete("HKCU\Software\Gmail\")
    If Err <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Number & vbcr & Err.Description,vbCritical,Title
    Else
        'MsgBox MyKey,vbInformation,Title
    End If  
End Sub
</script>
<body bgcolor="white">
<td><input name="txtUserID" title="Enter available User ID" TYPE="TEXT" SIZE="50"></td>
<br><br>
<INPUT NAME="btnWriteKey" title="WriteKey" TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="WriteKey" OnClick="Write2Registry()">
<INPUT NAME="btnReadKey" title="ReadKey" TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="ReadKey" OnClick="ReadFromRegistry()">
<INPUT NAME="btnDeleteKey" title="btnDeleteKey" TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="DeleteKey" OnClick="DeleteKeyFromRegistry()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much , can i save this file by html file instead hta file ??

Comment: @NumEduc You can but,  you can execute only with internet explorer and with security prompt !

Comment: how do it with internet explorer and with security prompt

Comment: @NumEduc I mean that internet explorer don't let you execute directly the vbscript code because it pop up to you a warning of security issue

Comment: yes i know because i testing this idea and i agree of security issue bu not execute it ??

Answer (score 0):

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\StackOverflow\VBS\Searchterm", tb1.value
```

`tb1.value` is a html text box.

Comment: so i have tested this 
http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1637005 with your code but not right